# What is the most RESTful way to update a resource in a non-idempotent way?

Tags: rest, web-applications, architecture, api-design

What is the most RESTful way to update part of a resource, where the generation of that resource is done server side, not on the client side. This is not an idempotent action, as the supporting data on the server may change between requests.

I'm creating a Rest API, and I've come to a design choice where I'm quite sure of the way to move forward.

I have a resource that I want to refresh, which involves creating a large json blob based on support data, then saving that json blob to a database before serving it back to the user.

My question is, what is the most RESTful way to perform this action?  As the client doesn't perform the calculations, and it also isn't idempotent as the data set may change between each call, I feel it is unnatural to use a PUT.

I settled on a POST, but that doesn't sit right either.

A third option would be to have a sub-resource that describes the action of refreshing - this doesn't feel correct either.

For example, I have a document:

```
GET /document/<documentId>
```

which would return something like:

```
"body": {
    "createdAt": "2019-01-01 12:00:00",
    "updatedAt": "2019-01-01 13:00:00",
    "name": "example",
    "location": "example",
    "city": "example"
}
```

These fields are generated by the server when the document is created, the client doesn't update them.

To allow the client to signal that they would like the server to regenerate the document, I have settled on:

```
POST /document/<documentId>
"body": {
   "param1": "updatedparam1",
   "param2": "updatedparam2"
}
```

An alternative approach would be to do something like:

```
POST /document/<documentId>/refresh
"body": {...}
```

but that feels more like an RPC call rather than REST.

Does this make sense logically?  I haven't seen many suggestions that `POST` can be to a single resource as opposed to a collection.

Please do let me know if I can expand on anything, I've been banging my head against this for a little while and have probably missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I settled on a POST, but that doesn't sit right either.

POST is [*fine*](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

HTTP semantics include rules about [invalidating](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) cached representations of resources.  Presumably, when you tell the server to regenerate the document, you don't want to keep using the old copy yourself.  So the target uri of the request should be the same as that which you use to `GET` the resource.

So:

```
POST /document/<documentId>
```

Is a good start.

An alternative, assuming the semantics match, would be to use [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) -- that's an appropriate choice to make if what you are doing is proposing replacement values for the representation.  In that case, the body of the request should be a "patch document".  You can, of course, define your own type of patch document; generic clients may already understand one or more of the standards [RFC-6902:JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) or [RFC-7386:JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) so you can potentially save some work by supporting one or more of the standard formats.

> I haven't seen many suggestions that POST can be to a single resource as opposed to a collection.

Part of the point of REST is that resources support a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) - "single resources" and "collection resources" look the *same*.  Historically, we got a bit unlucky with the [early specifications for POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-8.3), which were easily misinterpreted as CREATE.

But generic clients don't know, or care, whether or not the resource you specify in a web form is a "collection resource"; it just packs up the data and sends the request, confident that the server will know what to do.